# How to grab image links correctly? My scraper only make blank folders

Tags: python, web-crawler

My code is only making empty folders and not downloading images.

So, I think I need it to be modified so that the images can be clearly downloaded.

I tried to fix it by myself, but can't figure it out how to do.

Anyone please help me. Thank you!

```
import requests
import parsel
import os
import time

for page in range(1, 310): # Total 309pages
    print(f'======= Scraping data from page {page} =======')
    url = f'https://www.bikeexif.com/page/{page}'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    html_data = response.text
    selector = parsel.Selector(html_data)

    containers = selector.xpath('//div[@class="container"]/div/article[@class="smallhalf"]')

    for v in containers:
        old_title = v.xpath('.//div[2]/h2/a/text()').get()#.replace(':', ' -')
        if old_title is not None:
            title = old_title.replace(':', ' -')
        title_url = v.xpath('.//div[2]/h2/a/@href').get()
        print(title, title_url)

        if not os.path.exists('img\\' + title):
            os.mkdir('img\\' + title)

        response_image = requests.get(url=title_url, headers=headers).text
        selector_image = parsel.Selector(response_image)
        # Full Size Images
        images_url = selector_image.xpath('//div[@class="image-context"]/a[@class="download"]/@href').getall()

        for title_url in images_url:
            image_data = requests.get(url=title_url, headers=headers).content
            file_name = title_url.split('/')[-1]

            time.sleep(1)

            with open(f'img\\{title}\\' + file_name, mode='wb') as f:
                f.write(image_data)
                print('Download complete!!:', file_name)
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It helps to see if program works as you expect.

Comment: first: you use wrong xpath to get urls to images - you get `href` from `<a>` and you use it as url to image - but you should search `src` in `<img>`. Second: this page uses `JavaScript` for `"lazy loading"` and `<img>` doesn't keep url in `src` but in `data-src` - and when you scroll page then `JavaScript` copy `data-src` to `src - and this way browser load image when you scroll.

Comment: similar problem is with links `download` - they are created by JavaScript - but `requests`, `beautifulsoup`, `selector` can't run JavaScript. But displayed images have the same url (page only display it in scale) so you can use `data-src` from `img`

Comment: @furas OK, it seems like JavaScript is really hard to handle. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to create link `"download"` but `requests`/`urllib`/`beautifulsoup`/`lxml`/`parsel`/`scrapy` can't run `JavaScript` - and this makes problem.

But it seems page uses the same urls to display images on page - so you may use `//img/@src`

But this makes another problem because page uses `JavaScript` for `"lazy loading"` images and only first `img` has `src`. Other images have url in `data-src` (and normally Javascript copy `data-src` to `src` when you scroll page) so you have to get `data-src` to download some of images.

You need something like this to get `@src` (for first image) and `@data-src` (for other images).

```
images_url = selector_image.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//img/@src').getall() + \
             selector_image.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//img/@data-src').getall()
```

---

Full working code (with other small changes)

Because I use Linux so string `img\\{title}` creates wrong path
so I use `os.path.join('img', title, filename)` to create correct path on Windows, Linux, Mac.

```
import requests
import parsel
import os
import time

# you can define it once 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}

for page in range(1, 310): # Total 309pages
    
    print(f'======= Scraping data from page {page} =======')
    
    url = f'https://www.bikeexif.com/page/{page}'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    selector = parsel.Selector(response.text)

    containers = selector.xpath('//div[@class="container"]/div/article[@class="smallhalf"]')

    for v in containers:

        old_title = v.xpath('.//div[2]/h2/a/text()').get()#.replace(':', ' -')
        if old_title is not None:
            title = old_title.replace(':', ' -')

        title_url = v.xpath('.//div[2]/h2/a/@href').get()
        print(title, title_url)

        os.makedirs( os.path.join('img', title), exist_ok=True )  # it create only if doesn't exists

        response_article = requests.get(url=title_url, headers=headers)
        selector_article = parsel.Selector(response_article.text)
        
        # Full Size Images
        images_url = selector_article.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//img/@src').getall() + \
                     selector_article.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//img/@data-src').getall()

        print('len(images_url):', len(images_url))

        for img_url in images_url:

            response_image = requests.get(url=img_url, headers=headers)
            
            filename = img_url.split('/')[-1]

            with open( os.path.join('img', title, filename), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response_image.content)
                print('Download complete!!:', filename)
```